# How to make Header slide aswell when using createDrawerNavigator?

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation-drawer

**SOLVED**

I've found a solution, as can be seen in the answer below.

---

I've been trying quite a lot of different ways to solve this problem..

To allow the Header to not be above the drawer, I have nested navigators inside the `DrawerNavigator`.
When opening the header(with the property `drawerType: 'slide'`), it slides all the content of the nested navigator, but not the header itself. The header keeps its place, and the Drawer Content is rendered underneath the header.

Is there any way to make the header slide as well, besides rendering it separately for each component in the nested navigator?

I'll post some of my code if necessary, but it'd be quite a lot, if I have to link all that could be relevant. I'd mainly like to know if what I want is even possible.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

In an attempt to recreate this issue (in order to supply a comprehensible code-snippet), I realized that I have actually set the header as part of the Drawer Navigator. 
I've done this to be able to use a custom header, and every attempt I've made to set the header in the nested stacks, have resulted in it being overwritten by the drawer. Either, by not appearing, when giving the drawer `header: null`, or when not supplying any header at all, returning the default (blank) header, instead of my custom one.

I will further attempt to solve this and provide a code-snippet, solution or admittance of defeat, by the end of the day.

Comment: It probably would be best to share your code, even if it's on the longer side. You could always write a short "mockup" of your code that includes the essential parts, but isn't an exact copy/paste of what you have. See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you need guidelines for writing an example.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. @Das_Geek

Comment: I will be back tomorrow with a code-snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing my issue. What I apparently needed to do, was to put my bottomTabNavigator inside a stacknavigator, which then could be placed in the DrawerNavigator.

I attempted to make the code as dense as possible, in case anyone else ends up having the same issue, that I did.

---

**Header and Screen(s)**

```
const Header = () => <View style={{height: 50, width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}></View>

const Screen = ({color, navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: color}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white', width: 50, height: 50}}></View> 
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

---

**BottomTabNavigator and the StackNavigator**

```
const Bottom = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
  ScreenOne: {
    screen: props => <Screen color='green' {...props} />
  },
  ScreenTwo: {
    screen: props => <Screen color='yellow' {...props} />
  }
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'ScreenOne',
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: "blue",
    inactiveTintColor: "grey",
  },
  navigationOptions: {
    header: () => <Header />
  }
});

const Main = createStackNavigator(
{
  BottomTab: Bottom
});
```

---

**DrawerNavigator and AppContainer**

```
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
{
  MainFlow: {
    screen: Main,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }  
},
{
  hideStatusBar: false,
  drawerType: 'slide',
  drawerBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.9)',
  overlayColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
  drawerLockMode: 'locked-open',
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#fff',
    activeBackgroundColor: '#6b52ae',
  },
  navigationOptions: {
    header: null
  }
});

export const AppContainer = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);
```